# LSTM for multi-class sentiment analysis - requesting guidance

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm performing sentiment analysis on norwegian text. I'm doing (what i think are) the correct preprocessing steps, but for every tweak i make to my model i see the valuation accuracy go down after a few epochs. Does anyone know what the cause may be? I see models online producing good results for both accuracy and valuation accuracy, am i missing something?

The models ive tried:
Model 1:

```
# Define model architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, 100, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=25, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

```
# Compile and fit model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0015), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=8, batch_size=64, validation_data=(devX, devY))

# Evaluate model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
print(loss, accuracy)
```

Model 2:

```
# Define model architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, 100, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=25, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

# Compile and fit model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0015), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=8, batch_size=64, validation_data=(devX, devY))

# Evaluate model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
print(loss, accuracy)
```

Comment: Sounds like it’s overfitting after a few epochs. Do you have "enough" data? Are you training from scratch?

Comment: the dataset contains 10000 entries. I saw i was using totally wrong values for max_len and num_words. Avg sequence length is 8, while i had it set to encode for 128 length. Can this be part of issue?

Comment: Yes, in lstm it doesnt work well if you sequences are too long. Try to filter out too long sentences in you preprocesing. So you can train with less len.

Comment: This worked to an extent, but could an error be that there are no good word embeddings for norwegian? I tried downloading and using some of them, but i cant seem to get any better results.